# Get an object from two nested array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures, frontend

I want to have an object from two arrays and I did it in the following way.

```
for (var j = 0; j < rawDataRows.length; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
            var category = categories[i];
            var rowValue = rawDataRows[j];
            // here I do got the right value for category
            console.log(category); 
            console.log(rowValue);
            // but the following line doesn't interpret category as a variable
            formattedDataRows.push({category: rowValue});
        }
}
```

I was assuming I can get something like :

```
[{"category1": "value1"},{"category2": "value2"}, {"category3": "value3"}]
```

However, it turned out I got:

```
[{"category": "value1"}, {"category": "value2"}, {"category": "value3"}]
```

Can anyone point me where I am wrong? Also, if you have a better way achieving the goal, leave a comment please. Javascript only no jQuery or other framework. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Object literal syntax In ECMAScript 5 and lower doesn't allow you to specify a variable identifier as property name. Instead create the object first and then  use bracket notation.

```
var o = {};
o[category] = rowValue;
formattedDataRows.push(o);
```

With ECMAScript 6, you can do this:

```
formattedDataRows.push({[category]: rowValue});
```

though  of course support for that syntax is limited at this point in time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `categories[i].toString();` to get strings as you wished:

```js
var categories = ["category1", "category2", "category3"];
var rawDataRows = ["value1", "value2", "value3"];
var formattedDataRows = [];

for (var j = 0; j < rawDataRows.length; j++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    var category = categories[i].toString();
    var rowValue = rawDataRows[j].toString();

    var tmpObj = {}
    tmpObj[category] = rowValue
    formattedDataRows.push(tmpObj);
    
   //formattedDataRows.push({[category]: rowValue});
  }
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(formattedDataRows))
```

Comment: Your result isn't the same as what is described in the question. What he wants is a unique property name paired with a unique value for each object. I would question the wisdom of this, but it could be for a 3rd party API.

Comment: @squint I wouldn't assume that. He result was what he got so far, and he did not say that it is not what he wants to. I think it's wrong to do it the other way

Comment: He gave what he described as an assumption of what he could get, then showed what he got instead. Not sure what the purpose of your `.toString()` calls is. You're not using the `category` variable at all except to log it.

Comment: @squint i'm using it in `formattedDataRows.push({[category]: rowValue});`

Comment: @CodeiSir: lol, you just updated your answer to add it. :D In any case, there's not very much support out in the wild for that syntax at this point.

Comment: I just added  the `[]` but category was already there. Look at the edit history, what is your problem?

Comment: I don't have a problem. Of course `category` was already there; that's what the whole problem was to begin with. I  do  see you complain a lot when being corrected around here. Learn to take honest criticism and stop down voting people merely out of spite.

Comment: Wtf? I take criticism as very important, thats why I keep investigating the issues. For me the point was to make the least changes possible to the questioneers code to make it work, while even provided an working example. Am I a bad person, is this answer bad? I don't get your point. Also the first thing I was doing, was improving the readability of the Question. Not giving an asap solution.

Comment: It doesn't show based on the conversation above and your working example had the same problem as the original code.  A little humility goes a long way.

Comment: The only problem it had, is that it was giving "collection" instead of "collection1" wich I first overlooked. I did not change anything else in the code from the beginning. So no, the code was not the same as the original code. It was giving `[{"category": "value1"},{"category": "value2"}, {"category": "value3"}]`

Comment: @CodeiSir: But that's the whole problem. The issue was he that did not want `category` keys but rather `category1`, `category2`, `category3`. Now that you added the `[category]` syntax, that's what it does. The `toString()` calls aren't going to do anything related to what he's asking.

Comment: So he is missing the `"` in his example, that's why I miss-understood the problem. I also oversaw the 1,2,3 ... beeing dislexyc sucks, sometimes.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, and thankfull for you showing me my mistake.

Comment: No problem. And believe me, I experience the whole dyslexic thing too! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want both values to increment together (as it seems), also assuming the length of categories is the same length as rawdataRows, I think you really want a single loop instead of two loops:

```
for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
            var category = categories[i];
            var rowValue = rawDataRows[i];
```

Comment: Actually the categories length is different with rawDataRows. so I think using a nested loop should be correct way.

Comment: The example above threw me off:  [{"category1": "value1"},{"category2": "value2"}, {"category3": "value3"}]